# What happened to my answers and related reputation points?

Tags: support

I wasn't active on AVP during the last couple of months (just reading) and today I have noticed that large part (more than half) of my answers disappeared and the reputation points, related to these questions, disappeared as well. So as a result, I now have ~250 points instead more than 1K.

Any ideas what happened?

Answer (score 2):

We proceeded with the plan to [merge the audio portion of AVP with Sound Design SE](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343/merging-with-social-sound-design-now-in-progress), over the past few days more than 1500 questions have been migrated.

I [posted a final call to let folks know](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353/the-audio-merge-with-sound-design-se-is-now-underway) just before we started, with guidance on making sure you set up a linked account there.

*For the most part*, migrations are now complete. There are surely more purely sound questions that need to go over, but one by one as they're located - we got probably 95% of them using some bulk migration facilities that we have behind the scenes.

Your reputation for the bulk of your contributions is now visible on [Sound Design](http://sound.stackexchange.com), just click the 'sign up' link while you're signed into your AVP account and a profile will be created for you - then your contributions will be automatically associated with your account there. Feel free to [contact us](https://sound.stackexchange.com/contact) if something is missing, or didn't get associated with you correctly.

I know this comes as a bit of a shock to those that don't follow meta frequently (I put a system message on the main site, but in the beta theme, that can be somewhat easy to miss) and we apologize for that. However, going forward, we're going to end up with two sites distinctively stronger than a combined site would have been.

I'll be posting regarding the next steps for Video shortly, probably later today or early tomorrow (I just have to make certain of a few technical things, and then we're good to proceed).

Hang tight, this should all be settled shortly.